# Dividing floors into different number of apartments using CityEngine?

Tags: cityengine

Is it possible to divide each floor of a particular building into a different number of apartments?

Answer (score 1):

When you're in the floor-scope you can use for example the [split operation](http://cehelp.esri.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.procedural.cityengine.help/html/manual/cga/shape_operations/cga_so_split.html) to further subdivide the floor. This would look something like

```
Floor -->
    split(x) { ~1 : FloorZ | ~1 : FloorZ }

FloorZ -->
    split(z) { ~1 : Room | ~1 : Room }

Room -->
    _Your room definition_
```

You can further enhance this by e.g. splitting into three parts and leaving the center as a hallway.

Though if you just want that hallway you might consider using the [shapeO (at the bottom)](http://cehelp.esri.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.procedural.cityengine.help/html/manual/cga/shape_operations/cga_so_split.html) operation. Further operations you might consider to further divide the floor are `splitArea`, `shapeL`, `shapeU` and depending on the source shape `innerRectangle`.

If you already have the volume of the floor you either have to use `comp` to just select the floor (`comp(f){ bottom : Floor }`) and use with the above operations or you can only use `split` because it's the only operation that also works on volumes (afaik).